# Hiding a dropdown in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, combobox

I want to create a checkbox, If that is checked then it should display the dropdown. If not checked then it should hide the dropdown. This is how my code looks in Form.Designer.cs file.

```
        this.comboBox2.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.comboBox2.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
        "Database 1",
        "Database 2",
        "Database 3"});
        this.comboBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(165, 436);
        this.comboBox2.Name = "comboBox2";
        this.comboBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 21);
        this.comboBox2.TabIndex = 13;
        this.comboBox2.Text = "Database";
```

and My checkbox code in other file is

```
 if  (checkBox1.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (checkbox1.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
{
 this.combobox2.Visible = True;
}

else (checkbox1.CheckState == CheckState.Unchecked)
{
 this.combobox2.Visible = False;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying the same before even. Then I thought that may be I am coding at the wrong place. But i got my mistake and Actually my checkbox was checked inside the button click method and I was not clicking the button cause thats not my requirement. So Now i have moved my checkbox text outside the button click method.

Answer (score 6):

Use `Visible`

```
this.comboBox2.Visible = false;
```

Which would hide `comboBox2`.

Answer (score 1):

Your going to want something like this

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
            comboBox2.Visible = true;

        if (checkBox1.Checked == false)
            comboBox2.Visible = false;
```

And you will want to set the comboBox2 to visible = false in the properties tab, that should hopefully work.

Answer (score 0):

Or just in one line:

```
comboBox2.Visible = (checkbox1.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone experiences the following:
The head of the dropwdownlist is hidden, after setting it to `yourCombo.visible = false;` but the list itself is still visible, then you can add the following:

```
 yourComboBox.DroppedDown = false;
```